# How to make this code safe from SQL injection and use bind parameters

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

I found this code from a tutorial(Using Ajax,PHP And Mysql datatables) But I think it's not safe (The search field) because it's vulnerable to SQL Injection

How can I Use bind parameters in this code to prevent SQL Injection ?

```
<?php

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array( 'name', 'email', 'mobile', 'start_date');

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "id";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "root";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /*
     * Local functions
     */
    function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
    {
        header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
        die( $sErrorMessage );
    }


    /*
     * MySQL connection
     */
    if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
    }

    if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
    }


    /*
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /*
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    /*
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    */

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

Comment: btw this code is also vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: But as it won't store any thing it's not a big problem, Is it ?

Answer (score 1):

This code is using the old and now deprecated mySQL API.
Mysqli or PDO should be used instead. Then you can use parameterized queries.

Using mysqli:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $field);
$stmt->execute();
...
```

Using PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = :field');
$stmt->bindParam(':field', $field, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$stmt->execute();
...
```

See: [Overview of the MySQL PHP drivers](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php)

Note that the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) function is used in this code sample to handle characters that need escaping, it should thus prevent SQL injection. However, there could still be vulnerabilities in other parts of the code.
Injections are not always exploitable but obviously should never be allowed to occur.